# AngularJS - Is it possible to use ng-repeat to render HTML values?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, web, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS with a third party service that generates html responses. I want to use ng-repeat to render the HTML responses as a list, however Angular renders it as text.

Is it possible to use ng-repeat to render HTML property?

I've created this jsFiddle to demonstrate my issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/DrtNc/1/

Comment: For those of you viewing this question now, check out the top comment on the docs for [ngBindHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml). That worked for me while these answers did not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` will get you what you need.

```
<div ng:repeat="item in items" ng-bind-html-unsafe="item.html"></div>
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfreitas/aHfAp/

Documentation for the directive can be found here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

Comment: what if I would like to have custom directives used in item.html?

Comment: This is a couple of years old -- just wanted to inform new traffic that this method has been deprecated.  Here is a good way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Comment: Deprecated, use Matt Saunders' answer below

Answer (score 17):

The way I achieved this is by ng-bind-html inside the ng-repeat;

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
  <div ng-bind-html="comment.content"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Don't forget to use $sce for the html element you want to inject. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Answer (score 2):

item.html will always be interpreted as text. you have to convert it to html explicitly. [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/DrtNc/3/)

I have added a render function which will convert each string to html.

Comment: mmm ... I think it was too early to celebrate. your solution renders the innerHTML, what I really need is to render the entire HTML.

see my update :http://jsfiddle.net/DrtNc/4/

Comment: this doesnt work with nested tags or if you have some part of the text out of the tags