# Trouble using ng-repeat in AngularJS to render HTML values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I came across this post, which entails more or less exactly what I want to do: [AngularJS - Is it possible to use ng-repeat to render HTML values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408668/angularjs-is-it-possible-to-use-ng-repeat-to-render-html-values)

As of right now, the code looks like this, rendering correctly as text:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items.Items">
        {{item}}<br>
</div>
```

I want this to render as HTML now, so taking from that post, I have it looking something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items.Items" ng-bind-html-unsafe="item">
    <br>
</div>
```

However, nothing renders as a result. Does anyone know why that is? I have also tried setting ng-bind-html-unsafe to "{{item}}", which had no effect

Comment: Use ng-bind-html ... also out of curiosity what are you accomplishing with the  'br'?  The ng-repeat suggests you are repeating the 'div', a div by default is display block, which would stack the elements the same way you would achieve with a breaking line

Comment: Have you brought in the $sanitize module? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ? What does Items consist of ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Answer (score 1):

You should use ng-bind-html, 
and you could do that:

```
 $scope.myHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b>some</b> html');
```

See the **updated** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/406/).

In your case use some function or pass the array in the controller first:

```
$scope.getHtml = function(v){
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(v);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to mark the `html` that one is binding from the `.js` file to the `.html` which are in string format, as *safe*.

One way, it can be achieved is by making use of *AngularJS*'s dependency injection with `$sce`. One can read more about it, in length [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).

I have created a demo using a *list*, since you have shared only the HTML but not the JS, so I have assumed one and illustrated how to make use of it by trusting the HTML string using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`.

Refer [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/48r62eL2/).

Please have a look at the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind-html="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "Items": [{
      "data": "<p>Item 1</p>"
    }, {
      "data": "<p>Item 2</p>"
    }, {
      "data": "<p>Item 3</p>"
    }, {
      "data": "<p>Item 4</p>"
    }]
  }];
  $scope.items = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.data[0].Items, function(v, k) {
    $scope.items.push($sce.trustAsHtml(v.data));
  });
});
```